# excel to find first value within column that match criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For the same Project_Id if the first cell (in ‘Success’) is 1, than make all ‘output’ cells for that matching project_id a 1….
And for the same Project_Id if the first cell (in ‘Success’) is 0, than make all ‘output’ cells for that matching project_id a 0….
I had previous used:
`IF((COUNTIFS($A:$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,0)),0,1)`
However this is not correct as it does the following: if there are ANY 0’s in the range, than make it 0.
i have also tried this: `=IF(MIN(IF($A$2:$A$9=A2,$B$2:$B$9))=1,1,0)`
however it does not work properly particularly in cases where it should give a 1... not a 0...
Would appreciate some help!!

| column A | column B | column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project_Id | Success | output |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all values would be available, alternatively use `VLOOKUP()`:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2:A10,A2:B10,2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`XLOOKUP()` can give you desired output. Try-

```
=MAP(A2:A10,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,A2:A10,B2:B10,"",0,1)))
```

Single `XLOOKUP()` will also work, like-

```
=XLOOKUP(A2:A10,A2:A10,B2:B10,"",0,1)
```

To make input argument dynamic can use `A2:INDEX(A2:A50000,COUNTA(A2:A50000))`. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(A2:INDEX(A2:A50000,COUNTA(A2:A50000)),A2:A10,B2:B10,"",0,1)
```

I have used `MAP()` for dynamic spill results.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't not using map and taking in the range as the argument spill it as well?

Comment: @P.b You are correct. We can take range as lookup value argument for `XLOOKUP()`. Then only single function will work like `=XLOOKUP(A2:A10,A2:A10,B2:B10,"",0,1)`.